# Calculating the standard deviation of a log normal distribution from binned data where the bins are not of equal width

Tags: lognormal-distribution

I have a particle size distribution which I believe is log normal.  I need to calculate the number distribution which is apparantly the standard deviation of the log of the distribution.  Pretty simple except my data is in discrete bins and the bins are not uniform width.  I have seen that Sheppard's corrections could be useful but they assume a uniform bin width.

So how do I get the standard deviation of the data?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Chris.  You are correct -- but the principles that underlie Sheppard's corrections still apply and can be implemented with a maximum likelihood estimate.  That was my basis for searching for answers here and for suggesting the duplicates.  HTH.  BTW, I have applied these techniques specifically to particle size distributions and found they work well.